# Get Photos and Detailed Info for Many Foursquare Venues in one call

Tags: foursquare

I am working on an iPhone app which allows users to search Foursquare. I am using the venues/explore endpoint for the search which works great, but the results don't include the images for a place or the priceTier.

Right now I am calling /venues/VENUE_ID for each of the returned results, which is generating a lot of API calls. Is there a better way to get this info in a single call?

Related question: If I use the multi endpoint to batch these requests, does that count as a single request towards the limit or as multiple requests?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like you're worried about limits more than network latency? If you're worried that making the extra call to details will make you hit rate limits faster, this is actually why we generally ask developers to [cache](https://developer.foursquare.com/overview/ratelimits) details such as prices or photos :) A single multi request is not a single API call; it counts as how many requests are bundled into one.

There is a little help with photos though—if you pass in the `venuePhotos=1` param as part of an explore request, you ought to get back photos in the response.